# Android flash camera turns off just before taking the picture

Tags: android, camera

I am trying to build a custom camera.
I have  a button that starts/stops the flash. I set it to flash mode TORCH when it is on.
On some devices I was told that the flash stops just before the picture is taken. This happens on some android 2.3 devices.

Did anyone else run into this problem? Any ideas why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes I have found the same problem especially on HTC phones.

I have placed a condition to use FLASH_MODE_ON instead of FLASH_MODE_TORCH

```
List<String> pList = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedFlashModes();

if (getPackageManager().hasSystemFeature(PackageManager.FEATURE_CAMERA_FLASH)) {
    if (pList.contains(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH) && (!ManufacturerName.contains("htc"))) {
        parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_TORCH);
    }
    else
    if (pList.contains(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON)) {
        parameters.setFlashMode(Parameters.FLASH_MODE_ON);
    }
}
```

Comment: Sorry I added the declaration above for you.

List<String> pList = mCamera.getParameters().getSupportedFlashModes();